Strapi error while installing dependencies (windows)
I was about to start strapi project by "npx create-strapi-app backend-strapi --quickstart" and "npx create-strapi-app@latest backend-strapi", but while installing dependencies, i have an error.
PS D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia> npx create-strapi-app@latest backend-strapi
? Choose your installation type Quickstart (recommended)

We can't find any auth credentials in your Strapi config.

Create a free account on Strapi Cloud and benefit from:

- ✦ Blazing-fast ✦ deployment for your projects
- ✦ Exclusive ✦ access to resources to make your project successful
- An ✦ Awesome ✦ community and full enjoyment of Strapi's ecosystem

Start your 14-day free trial now!


? Please log in or sign up. Skip
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi.
Creating files.
Error while installing dependencies:
npm warn config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm warn config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
npm warn config `--include=optional` to include them.
npm warn config
npm warn config       Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated mailcomposer@3.12.0: This project is unmaintained
npm warn deprecated @koa/router@10.1.1: **IMPORTANT 10x+ PERFORMANCE UPGRADE**: Please upgrade to v12.0.1+ as we have fixed an issue with debuglog causing 10x slower router benchmark performance, see https://github.com/koajs/router/pull/173
npm warn deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm warn deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm warn deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/blob/master/VERSION_NOTES.md
npm warn deprecated buildmail@3.10.0: This project is unmaintained
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'D:\\Programowanie\\Projekty\\czar-ognia\\backend-strapi\\node_modules\\@swc\\core',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\@swc\core'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'D:\\Programowanie\\Projekty\\czar-ognia\\backend-strapi\\node_modules\\@swc\\core'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'D:\\Programowanie\\Projekty\\czar-ognia\\backend-strapi\\node_modules\\@swc',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\@swc'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4051,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'D:\\Programowanie\\Projekty\\czar-ognia\\backend-strapi\\node_modules\\@swc'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'D:\\Programowanie\\Projekty\\czar-ognia\\backend-strapi\\node_modules\\@strapi',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\@strapi\admin\dist\ee'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'D:\\Programowanie\\Projekty\\czar-ognia\\backend-strapi\\node_modules\\@strapi\\admin\\dist\\ee'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]
npm error code 1
npm error path D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\esbuild
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm error D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:133
npm error     throw new Error(`Expected ${JSON.stringify(versionFromPackageJSON)} but got ${JSON.stringify(stdout)}`);
npm error           ^
npm error
npm error Error: Expected "0.19.11" but got "0.21.5"
npm error     at validateBinaryVersion (D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:133:11)
npm error     at D:\Programowanie\Projekty\czar-ognia\backend-strapi\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:284:5
npm error
npm error Node.js v18.20.4
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\pleku\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-01T18_41_39_276Z-debug-0.log
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addBreadcrumb')
    at C:\Users\pleku\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:36:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Module.captureStderr (C:\Users\pleku\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:35:37)
    at createProject (C:\Users\pleku\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-project.js:133:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async createQuickStartProject (C:\Users\pleku\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-quickstart-project.js:18:3)
    at async initProject (C:\Users\pleku\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\create-strapi-app\dist\create-strapi-app.js:172:3)

If anyone knows what can cause this, please let me know,
I tried changing Node version to 22, 20 and 14 (with NPM v6.14.18)

After initializing Strapi, Try doing:
npm i @swc/core
Strapi uses SWC core, which is a fast alternative for babel.

For me there was problem that strapi had in the default template references to better-sqlite3 (8.6.0).
Node ^18 does not fully support this version.
Upgrading better-sqlite3 package worked:
npm install better-sqlite3@^9.0.0

